# datePicker dateFormat

Tags: jquery

I am trying to format the date returned from the date-picker and it is not working, it keeps returning the default `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I'm using the following code:

```
$('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

Comment: What's your HTML? Are you sure the ID used in your jQuery is the same as in your HTML?

Comment: Some samples: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

Comment: So far I figure it has something to do with cache. Don't matter what changes I make e.g. delete the datepicker code, it still shows up. Going to restart machine and see.

Comment: Restart machine and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

to get your date formatted use:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```